# .htaccess : subdomain not mapping correctly

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I am trying to make this work:

forum.domain.com -> domain.com/forum

Problem is that this works, but then when I try to access topic of a forum, it says 404.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.domain\.com\$1$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.forum\.domain\.com\$1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://forum.domain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/index.php [R=301,P]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax error and `HTTP_HOST` only matches domain name without URI.

Replace your code with (assumin `mod_proxy` is enabled):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?forum\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /forum/index.php/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: This has the same problem. http://forum.domain.com/topic/108-Test-topc/ doesnt work but http://forum.domain.com/index.php/topic/108-Test-topc/ wors. http://forum.domain.com/ works and open the home page of the forum though. So how to remove that index.php requirement from the topic view?

Comment: No luck: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?forum\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /forum/index.php [R=301,P]

Comment: Why are you using `[R=301,P]` flags? You should use either `[R=301,L]` or else `[L,P]`

Comment: I need to keep forum.domain.com visible in the addressbar. The code you provided redirects to the domain.com/forum and change the URL?